# Asymmetric communication between two symmetric parties?

Tags: information-theory, cryptography, communication-protocols, physics, philosophy

(sci-fi-esque question inspired by Counterpart).

A portal between our world (called $A$) and a parallel world that's exactly the same (called $B$) opens up. Bob sees himself through this portal.

$A$-Bob says hello, but since he's in the exact same circumstance, $B$-Bob also says hello at the exact same time. Basically, every communication $A$-Bob and $B$-Bob try to have with each other ends up being useless, because they both keep doing/saying the exact same thing at the exact same time.

Is it possible for $A$-Bob to have asymmetric communication with $B$-Bob? E.g. get to a point where $A$-Bob and $B$-Bob can actually communicate with each other, instead of talking over each other with the same message.

Assume that both worlds have the same exact "RNG seed". So, for example, if $A$-Bob says "I'll flip a coin", then $B$-Bob will've said the same thing, and both coins will land the same. Also, the worlds aren't "mirrored", so $A$-Bob raising his right hand = $B$-Bob raising his right hand (as opposed to a mirror, where $B$-Bob would've raised his left instead). Lastly, assume that, where it makes sense, quantum experiments also have the same "RNG seed". So if $A$-Bob considered the spin of his favorite electron, it'd turn out to be the same as $B$-Bob's favorite electron's spin.

Lastly, to clarify, the two worlds are "independent". Nothing is actively forcing them to be the same. All that's the case is that they both have the same "initial conditions" and "RNG seed".

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "asymmetric communication" or how specifically that differs from "communication" in general.  I don't think you've made the scenario precise enough.  Are you assume that the world evolves deterministically?  (e.g., via classical Newtonian physics rather than quantum mechanics?)  What would it even mean to communicate in this setting?  Normally to communicate, there have to be multiple possibilities for the message or input we're trying to communicate, but it's not clear how that arises in your world where everything is purely deterministic.

Comment: Finally, it's not clear what you're assuming about how the state of one world can/does affect the evolution of the other world.  If A-Bob can "see" B-Bob, that implies a kind of influence and communication.  If A-Bob can "see" B-Bob, that means photons are travelling from B-Bob to A-Bob's eyes and are affecting A-Bob, in which case the two worlds aren't actually independent.  I'm wondering if you're really asking a question about physics.  I'm unsure whether this is a question about computer science at all.